# Load model resources angular.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have 2 tables posts and photos and there relationship is

```
post has_many :photos
photos belongs_to :posts
```

I load the posts through angular and display them to the user and all the content works perfect but when I try to display the photos they just don't show heres the code I am using

```
...loop through results
   //this works
   <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
   //this doesn't
   <img src="{{post.photos.first.image}}" />
...end
```

I have been using Ruby on Rails and this is the syntax they use, I know its probably wrong but does anybody know the correct syntax.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<img ng-src="{{post.photos[0].image}}" />
```

But check the model (the JSON return from Firebug, or debug from Firebug) to make sure the `photos` field exists and is array. The `[0]` should take the first item, *if it exists*. If it doesn't, you should better hide the image with `ng-if`.

Also make sure the path given by `.image` is correct for your application, you may need to enhance it as: `ng-src="/correct/path/{{post.photos[0].image}}"`.

Comment: thanks for helping I did what you asked and the checked the response from firebug. But it seems as though the response is only returning the post, and not the photos any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, by photos you don't mean the binary, rather the path to the binary...

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by binary, What I am currently doing is quering the posts#index and returning json, the json that is returned does not seem to include the photos, I don't know if I have to also make a query for photos too, if so how would I do that?

Comment: Check the JSON response. What fields are available? Is the path to the photo available? If it is, is something serving the images in this path?